# One app, 2 url, how to do (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, https, sitemap

I have a problem managing my sites in node.js
I have a server, a node.js app but 2 urls.
According to the url, the display is different thanks to config / local / XXX.json

I have a problem for
- HTTPS management: I have 2 certificates. One is in place but I do not know how to set up the other. Certificates are currently managed in config / env / production
- Sitemap management. As I have 2 url, so I have 2 sites map. The access is not the same: 30% of the pages are identical but the rest (like a blog) are different.

To have the same engine for the 2 sites is to have manage only one put on line during modification.
How to continue (or not) to have a technical site but to be able to manage the specificities of each URL (certificate, sitemaps ...)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Both URLs are on the same IP, and you're doing the SSL termination at Node? It does support SNI, so it should be possible to configure - although very old clients e.g. Android 2.x don't support that. Alternatively you could obtain one certificate that covered both URLs, but again that might not be supported by very old clients.

Comment: is your question how to renew the TLS certs or how to use both URLs

Comment: It's the same IP.

Using the 2 URLs does not pose a problem. It redirects to my server. This url is used to set up a particular json.

My problem is that I can only put a TLS certificate online. And since the production file is generated at start, once the file has been put in place for the first URL, the second one has obligatorily the same one, whereas no.